# Can't write data to file

Tags: java

I'm new to this site, java and programming in generall. You'd say I'm a total noob. So here is my problem:
I just started working with files, so I try various things for practice. Say i want to write a lot of numbers in a file. If I use this code, everything works fine:

```
    int value = 0;
    int max = 10000;
    try {
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("newFile.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            value = i;
            wr.write(value + " ");
        }
        wr.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        println(e);
    }
```

newFile.txt is created with all the expected numbers.
But if use this code to write randomly selected numbers from 0 to 9,

```
    int value = 0;
    int max = 10000;
    try {
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("newFile.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            value = RandomGenerator.getInstance().nextInt(0,9);
            wr.write(value + " ");
        }
        wr.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        println(e);
    }
```

newFile.txt is created but is filled with    << ‱‷‱‰′‱′‵‶‰′‸′‵‸‸″‰‰‵‶‵‱‶‵ >>.

Note that RandomGenerator is a class from acm package -a package that my study book uses in examples.

I've tried different classes like BufferedWriter and PrintWriter but I get the same output.

So, am I missing something here? I really can't figure it out.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Thank you for your quick responses. I 've already tried to get the output via `System.out.println` alongside with `wr.write`. The screen output was as expected, but the file output was not.
Something more odd occured though: I run it again but with a range from 0 to 10. The only thing I changed was this line:

```
value = RandomGenerator.getInstance().nextInt(0,10);
```

Now newFile.txt is as expected.. Any ideas why is that??

thanx

Comment: Are you sure your code is `wr.write(value + " ");`, and not `wr.write(value + ' ');`?

Comment: have you printed out  the `value` in each iteration to see what you're expecting in your file

Comment: Try temporarily doing a `System.out.println` instead of `wr.write` to see what values `RandomGenerator` is producing. It may be about `RandomGenerator` itself and not the file IO part.

Comment: This code works fine for me. You must have different code over there (disregarding the Random generator, because if it does return an int, it should work regardless of anything else).

Comment: Did you add the ACM.jar file into your project?

Comment: @JB Nizet: yes, I'm sure

Comment: @Rafael Battesti: yes, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Renato: It's the same. I copied-pasted it.

Comment: Then I can't see how you could have such a result. Maybe you're not looking at the right file. Or maybe you forgot to recompile and are using an older version of the code that does something else.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I'm a noob, but I konw SOME things, man. I'm sure that I'm looking at the right file. Also, I tried a lot of stuff so forgeting to recompile is out of the table, too. I edited the question, check it out. Thank you

Comment: I took your code, executed it, and it produces a sequence of numbers, as expected. There is no need to get defensive. I'm not saying you don't know anything, but that doesn't prevent you from making mistakes, like all humans, including myself, do. What happens if you recompile the original code, delete the file, run it again, and reopen the file?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Don't get me wrong man. I did not get defensive, I was just being sarcastic with myself. I think I've tried everything that could be done. I  even tried it on a different computer.

Answer (score 1):

I think nothing is very wrong with your code.

A slightly altered version that works without your random library:

```
int max = 10000;
Random random = new Random();

try(FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("newFile.txt")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        int value = random.nextInt(9);
        wr.write(value + " ");
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I ran the above, I got the expected file with lots of numbers from 0 to 8.

If your Random library does indeed return a `int`, you should definitely get the numbers in the file, even if in the wrong range.

Perhaps the problem is when you visualize the file? It might be encoding, given that this code uses your platform's default encoding (which may be very strange to cause this issue).

Try using this as a writer to ensure the file is written with UTF-8:

```
try(OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("newFile.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
```

Comment: nextInt() does return an `int` , that's for sure. If I display the output on the screen, it works fine. The baffling thing is that  it also works fine with the file, if the range is 0 to 10 (or greater).

Comment: @antonis Did you try using the OutputStreamWriter as I suggested above? This must be encoding issues. With this writer, you will certainly get UTF-8, so you can use a text editor and make sure you open the file with UTF-8 encoding and it just must work!

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it, but still have the same problem:  If the range is 11 or bigger, it's OK. But if it's smaller, it just won't work.  I also tried `Random` instead of `RandomGenerator` but I get the same result.

Comment: Well, as a last shot, try `Integer.toString( value ) + " "` instead of `value + " "`.

Comment: Also, how are you running your Java code? If you're doing `java` manually, what does `java --version` print? What does `Charset.defaultCharset()` print?

Comment: java -version prints `java version "1.8.0_73"   Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 25.73-b02)  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode, sharing)`   and  `Charset.defaultCharset()` prints `windows-1253`.

Comment: Also, I 've already tried `Integer.toString(value)` , but as you 'd guess, same result.

Comment: The only things that may cause this problem are: 1. encoding used to write data (we tried UTF-8 with the code I suggested, and the platform default with the original code). 2. encoding used to read the data. That I cannot know unless you send me the file, but you should be able to use Sublime or similar to open the file with a specific encoding. 3. your conversion from int to String, which we also addressed. 4. your JVM has a bug, which can be ruled out here as you use a standard JVM. Sorry, but as far as I can see, only nothing else can influence this.

Comment: I don't think it's an encoding problem. The output is normal if range > (0,10) , and this shouldn't be the case if it was an encoding issue, right?  Anyway, thank you for your time. If and when I figure it out, I'll let you know what the issue was. cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Random;


public class Randomfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int value = 0;
        int max = 10000;
        try {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("D:\\newFile.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
                value = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
                wr.write(value + " ");
            }
           wr.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("e:"+e);
        }
    }
 }
```